# make yield.put happen one after the other in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have the yield.put to happen one after the other as async behaviour is no good for me for this implementation.

generator function

```
export function * createUser (action) {
  try {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =
      'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('userAccessToken')
    console.log(action.payload)
    const user = yield call(axios.post, api.createUser, action.payload)
    yield put(actionCreators.addUserSuccess(user.data))

    const qs = queryString.stringify(action.payload)
    const endpoint = `${api.createUser}?${qs}`
    console.log(endpoint)
    const users = yield call(axios.get, endpoint)
    console.log(users)

    yield put(actionCreators.fetchUsersSuccess(users.data))
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actionCreators.addUserFailure(error))
  }
}
```

I have this generator function and I want 
`yield put(actionCreators.addUserSuccess(user.data))` to complete before `yield put(actionCreators.fetchUsersSuccess(users.data))` is called

any assistance on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Here are some approaches to this:

- Make `actionCreators.addUserSuccess` blocking
- Dispatch another action when `actionCreators.addUserSuccess` completes

---

### Make `actionCreators.addUserSuccess` blocking

There is the [`putResolve`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#putresolveaction) effect creator for blocking an effect. This is only useful when addUserSuccess returns a promise that you need to be resolved.

```
    const response = yield putResolve(actionCreators.addUserSuccess(user.data))
    // use resolved promise in next operation
```

### Dispatch another action when `actionCreators.addUserSuccess completes`)

Where `actionCreators.addUserSuccess` doesn't return a promise, this is a better way to go.

Dispatch another action when `actionCreators.addUserSuccess` completes then [`take`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takepattern) that action.

```
    while (true) {
      // say this is the action type that is dispatched in the 
      // middleware that runs actionCreators.addUserSuccess
      const action = yield take('FETCH_USERS'); 
      yield put(actionCreators.fetchUsersSuccess(action.users.data))
    }
```

Comment: I did not understand how to check if actionCreators.addUserSuccess completed as my actionCreator does not return a promise and can you help me with the code if possible

Comment: What does `actionCreators.addUserSuccess` do? You may just need to `take` the action type that it is dispatching to the store if it only updates the store without side effects.